# When I create a file in the same folder as the app itself on a Mac app, where does the file go?

Tags: python, macos

I created the following Python test program (test.py).

This simply creates a file called testWrite.txt where the executable is located.

**test.py**

```
import os
import sys
path_w = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])+'/testWrite.txt'
with open(path_w, mode='w') as f:
    f.write('testWrite')
```

In this state, when I run test.py in Terminal or AnacondaPrompt, testWrite.txt is generated in the same location as test.py.

I then made this file executable using Pyinstaller.

```
pyinstaller  --noconsole -n testApp test.py
```

TestApp was created in the dist folder.

And when I run dist\TestApp, the files are not created in the same folder as dist\TestApp. However, no error has occurred, and the file itself seems to be saved somewhere.

When I check the contents of the file with the read command at the same time as the write, it seems that I can read it properly.

When I create a file in the same folder as the app itself on a Mac app, where does the file go?

Comment: Why not add `print(path_w)` and figure it out? Or even better you `logging` and support a --debug flag for all the troubleshooting you might need in the future

Comment: I have a weird python setup but for me the file was created in the dist folder: `./dist/test/testWrite.txt`

Comment: Thank you ,urban! When I checked the location of the file in that way, I found that there was a file in "testapp.app/Contents/MacOS/testWrite.txt".